# Most efficient/secure way to get user information

Tags: php, get, store

I'm making a profile system for users on a website. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient and secure way to get and display their info on the profile page. The profiles will be rather large, containing potentially dozens of text fields plus images.

I don't really want to query the database every time the page loads because that seems very inefficient. And I think it would be too much data to store in a session.

So my question is: What methods are available to accomplish this and which do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't agree with your view point (db query is efficient) you can use session to store your data.
Start a session at beggining of page and use the variable $_SESSION to store and use data as you like.

Page 1 (login or something)

```
// this starts the session 
session_start(); 

// this sets variables in the session 
$_SESSION['test']='testing';
```

Page 2 (profile page)

```
// this starts the session 
session_start(); 

// this echos variables in the session 
echo $_SESSION['test']; //output 'testing'
```

Comment: That's part of my question. Is it more efficient to query every time? Also, is there a downside to storing that much data in the session? I'm just looking for outside opinions - I'm not sure what method is best.

Comment: It is up to you. $_SESSION variable is considered very secure. Database query is efficient because is exactly his job, handling small/large amounts of data.

Comment: better do just one query and store the data in $_SESSION variables. helps you keep your DB load low. no downside there... common practice... and (theoretically) more secure than getting the data from the DB as $_SESSION is PHP internal environment, DB is not...

Comment: Thanks for the opinions. I know it was kind of a silly question, just want to make sure things work well.